# How to use "Loop Cut" and prevent interruption / disconnection

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, loop

I am in progress in creating a 3D object but I encounter difficulties.

How to prevent interruption / disconnection when using the "Loop Cut" tool?

[image]

[image]
Why here is not working?

[image]
And here is working?

Comment: loop cut will only happen if it crosses quads, so maybe here you have a problem of ngons or inner faces, if you don't find please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly as I don't have your model but by seeing the gif I guess there is some problem with that face. The shading of the face does not look proper to me. I have marked that face in the image below

Probably some edge/vertex is missing and that can be the reason why it is not showing for those faces

[image: See this image]